# CodePush not updating new version

Tags: react-native, code-push

I have version `5.0.1` of my application with two versions released on CodePush.

I do not bump up any Version or Build numbers. So `5.0.1` and Build `1`.

The first version `v1` gets installed, but after I make a new release (`v2`), the bundle doesn't get downloaded or installed anymore.

`v1`:

[image]

`v2`:

[image]

I use the following to add CodePush to my app:

```
const CodePushHomeScreen = codePush(HomeScreen);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Default behavior restricts updates to only occur once an app is restarted. I would first confirm that updates aren't being registered after a restart of the app and/or switch things over to update on resume instead using this snippet:

```
let codePushOptions = { checkFrequency: 
codePush.CheckFrequency.ON_APP_RESUME };

class MyApp extends Component {
}

M HomeScreen App = codePush(codePushOptions)(HomeScreen);
```

If that doesn't work, delete the two updates and release two more using the flag:

`--targetBinaryVersion "~5"`